# R - Update a Value in One Column Based on Criteria in Other Tables

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I want to update the values of a table based on the value found in a specific column of another table. i.e.

```
tb1<-data.table(w=c('xray','yankee','zulu','alpha','bravo','charlie', 
                    'xray','yankee','zulu','alpha','bravo','charlie'),
                x=c('alpha','bravo','charlie','xray','yankee','zulu',
                    'xray','yankee','zulu','alpha','bravo','charlie'),
                y=c('zulu','yankee','xray','charlie','bravo','alpha'))

tb2<-data.table(z= c('alpha','bravo','charlie'),
                z2=c('zalpha','zbravo','zcharlie'))
```

In column "w"of tb1, values that do not appear in col "z" of tb2 should be replaced by "NONE".  This code actually does the work for this short table.

```
tb1[,"w":=lapply(tb1$w,function(u){ifelse((u %in% tb2$z),u,"NONE")})]
```

However, the actual table has more than two million records and the above instruction is very slow (>20 mins before stopping it).  Eventually, I need to substitute all values in columns "w',"x" and "y" of tb1 that are not in tb2$z.  What would be the correct "data.table" approach to accomplish this?  I have tried subsetting it assuming that it would be more efficient to group the values before doing a replacement. None of the combinations I have used with .SD give me the correct answer.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `%chin%` to create the logical index of elements in 'w' that are not found in 'z', then assign (`:=`) the corresponding elements in 'w' to "NONE".

```
tb1[!w %chin% tb2$z, w:= "NONE"]
tb1
#         w       x       y
# 1:    NONE   alpha    zulu
# 2:    NONE   bravo  yankee
# 3:    NONE charlie    xray
# 4:   alpha    xray charlie
# 5:   bravo  yankee   bravo
# 6: charlie    zulu   alpha
# 7:    NONE    xray    zulu
# 8:    NONE  yankee  yankee
# 9:    NONE    zulu    xray
#10:   alpha   alpha charlie
#11:   bravo   bravo   bravo
#12: charlie charlie   alpha
```

If we need to change all the columns in 'tb1' based on the 'z' column of 'tb2', we can loop through the columns of 'tb1' and assign as showed earlier.

```
nm1 <- names(tb1)
for(j in seq_along(tb1)){
  tb1[!tb1[[j]] %chin% tb2$z, nm1[j] := "NONE"]
}
tb1
#          w       x       y
# 1:    NONE   alpha    NONE
# 2:    NONE   bravo    NONE
# 3:    NONE charlie    NONE
# 4:   alpha    NONE charlie
# 5:   bravo    NONE   bravo
# 6: charlie    NONE   alpha
# 7:    NONE    NONE    NONE
# 8:    NONE    NONE    NONE
# 9:    NONE    NONE    NONE
#10:   alpha   alpha charlie
#11:   bravo   bravo   bravo
#12: charlie charlie   alpha
```

Comment: Works like a charm!  Thank you!

Comment: @LDBerriz Glad to know that works.  Can I know how much time it took in your original dataset?

Comment: Less than a second ... 1437240 records in 6 columns.

Comment: Actually, 20 msecs.     user  system elapsed 
                                     0.02    0.00    0.02

Comment: @LDBerriz Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: btw. unlike `%in%` the `%chin%` is not yet optimized to use index, but I believe it is just a matter of time